# npm was installed using sudo?

Tags: linux, macos, npm, file-permissions, sudo

npm was installed on my machine few months ago but I do not remember if I installed it using sudo or not.

Now, I am reading about Appian and I see that it should not be installed using sudo so I would like to check before proceeding how did I install it few months back.

How do I find out if my npm was installed with sudo or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply ls the executable. On my macbook it showed my username. I imagine if it was installed using sudo the permissions would be root-root:

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin  38 Mar 14  2015 /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

Comment: how would "root-root" perm look like then?

Comment: similar to this: (note the 2 root's meaning root user, root group) : lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  root  38 Mar 14  2015 /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js